# Android SpeechRecognizer words pool / context

Tags: android, speech-recognition, android-speech-api

When using Android SpeechRecognizer I can see that it also uses my contacts as source for words to resolve some of what been said and translate it into text.

Is there an api to supply a bank of words for the speech recognition engine, instead of adding contacts which is not reasonable...

Comment: Do you mean specifically for the Android Speech API (when Google is set to the default) or for an alternative speech API you could use?

Comment: Specifically for the android SpeechRecognizer api... a list of sentances that it would try to recover the speech from, like it is doing with the contacts names

Comment: Kaarel's answer is technically correct - there are no additional parameters in the native API. There are external RESTFul services you can use instead though, to resolve the speech and use a machine learning back-end to 'train' your model to identify contact information.

Answer (score 2):

Let's be precise with the names. There is no "Google SpeechRecognizer" nor "google api". There is Android's RecognitionService (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionService.html). This is an interface, which comes with some pre-defined constants and callbacks, none of which offer what you want. The "Google App" does implement this interface however, and might extend it in some ways but these extensions are not publicly documented as far as I know.

Directly unrelated to Android, there is also Google's Cloud Speech API (https://cloud.google.com/speech/) which offers something towards the feature that you want.